# getting error while serializing an object list

Tags: c#, windows, serialization

I receive this error invoking a method on a button click event handler:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

This is my handler:

```
private async Task WriteAsync() 
        {
            var objectGraph = getObjectGraph();
           var serializer = new  DataContractSerializer(typeof(List<Car>));
            using (var stream = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForWriteAsync(myFile, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting)) 
            {
                serializer.WriteObject(stream, objectGraph);
            }
            txt.Text = "Write Succeed !!!";
        }
```

Comment: Is the Car decorated with DataContract/Members attributes?

Comment: no.. actually i am studying serialization so dont know about "attributes" ... can u please elaborate ?

Comment: https://github.com/aumcode/nfx/blob/master/Source/Testing/Manual/WinFormsTest/SerializerForm2.cs#L605-610
notice the "DataContract". You need to tell the system what is serializable by DC serializer. This is because it is built for "between systems" protocols so you need to specify what is a "visible format" outside of CLR/>Net paradigm.
There are also "transparent" serializers like MSBinaryFormatter or NFX.Slim that do not require any decorations.

Look at this project for various sers techniques and benchamarks (DC,Protobuf+JSON+many more): https://github.com/aumcode/serbench

Answer (score 0):

Look examples for DataContractSerializer here: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)